# How to translate 2-D list of Strings using ML-Kit in Android (Java)

Tags: android, translate, google-mlkit

I have created and downloaded Translation model for the Gujarati language. Now .translate() function is working fine for individual Strings but is there any way to translate whole 2D List of Strings at once using Google's ML-Kit?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, instead you have to translate each string separately.

Comment: I want to translate data and store in excel file, how can I wait for all translations to finish before creating the file ?

Comment: You can use Tasks API to wait for all specified tasks to be completed.
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks#whenAll(com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3C?%3E...)